# Issue with ajax and possibly google maps

Tags: php, html, ajax

What is wrong with this code using ajax? I am trying to replace the content of a div with an echoed string from a php file, and its not working. I also have Google maps in the site, which may be the issue as I can get test cases to work in other files. If google maps is the issue, how would i use ajax with google maps?

```
function update(){
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && (httpRequest.status == 200) || (httpRequest.status == 0))
    {
        document.getElementById("form").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","update.php", true);
xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`httpRequest` isn't defined anywhere.  You probably want:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && (xmlhttp.status == 200) || (xmlhttp.status == 0))
```

(Hint: Chrome's JS console is great for debugging.  Open with the View -> Developer -> JavaScript Console menu item.)

Comment: @BenSinger - oh, and note that you probably want your parens to be like this: `xmlhttp.readyState==4 && (xmlhttp.status == 200 || xmlhttp.status == 0)`.  I believe the expression above will be true any time status == 0, regardless of readyState.